# Regex for string with spaces and special characters - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have been using Regex to match strings embedded in square brackets [*] as:

```
new Regex(@"\[(?<name>\S+)\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I also need to match some codes that look like:
[TESTTABLE: A, B, C, D]

it has got spaces, comma, colon

Can you please guide me how can I modify my above Regex to include such codes.
P.S. other codes have no spaces/special charaters but are always enclosed in [...].

Comment: it helps if you tag your question with the appropriate programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex myregex = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]*)]")
```

will match all characters that are not closing brackets and that are enclosed between brackets. Capture group `\1` will match the content between brackets.

Explanation (courtesy of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com)):

```
Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\]]*)»
   Match any character that is NOT a ] character «[^\]]*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character “]” literally «]»
```

This will also work if you have more than one pair of matching brackets in the string you're looking at. It will *not* work if brackets can be nested, e. g. `[Blah [Blah] Blah]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[([^\]:])*(?::([^\]]*))?\]/
```

Capture group 1 will contain the entire tag if it doesn't have a colon, or the part before the colon if it does.

Capture group 2 will contain the part after the colon. You can then split on ',' and trim each entry to get the individual parts.